# How does C++ handle non-virtual function calls on a pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've searched but couldn't find any results (my terminology may be off) so forgive me if this has been asked before. I'm probably using the wrong search keywords.

I understand how vtables are used to handle virtual function calls on a pointer, specifically when "use after free" vulnerabilities come into play.
However, suppose you have a pointer to myclass and you call function myfunction on it when myfunction is NOT implemented virtually?
According to a bit of reading, there is one less fetch, IE instead of fetching the address of the function, then fetching the function, then calling, it is fetched directly.

Howver what confuses me is how this would work if the pointer to myclass had been freed before use.
EDIT: previous paragraph unclear, I am trying to figure out what sort of undefined behaviour might be expected.

Can anyone clear this up for me? If my question is unclear I will clarify...

CodeLion

EDIT:

```
MyClass *myclass;
free(myclass);
myclass->DoSomething();

Declaration of DoSomething()
void DoSomething{...} // NOT virtual void DoSomething
```

Comment: "how this would work if the pointer to myclass had been freed before use" - it would be *undefined behaviour*, so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: can you paste a few lines of code please that will depict what you mean?

Comment: Yes but undefined behaviour can lead to things such as code execution or memory corruption in certain cases, such as a virtual call on a freed pointer. @ oli

done @ bits

Comment: @BrianBTB: So what exactly are you asking here?  Are you asking "what kinds of undefined behaviour might I expect to observe?"?

Comment: I think he is asking how non-virtual function members are implemented.

Comment: @Veritas: That's what I assumed, but I don't understand the OP's final paragraph.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes that is what I am asking, and should I remove that paragraph? I guess the question was clear without it

Comment: Now you have two sources of UB. Calling `free` on an uninitialized pointer, and calling a member function through it. And it is still completely unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza: probably he wants to know this: "If I have a NULL pointer or a garbage pointer to a class, what happens if I do `garbage_ptr->DoSomething()` if `DoSomething` is not virtualm will the program actually enter into the `DoSomething` function with `this` beeing NULL or garbage or will it crash before entering the `DoSomething` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the address of the function is known at compile time because it can't possible be anything else. Whereas with a virtual function it needs to use the vtable to determine what function to call at runtime.

If the memory where your pointer to the object the method is being called on was already freed then it would just be undefined behavior the same as if it was a virtual function call because the pointer doesn't point to an instance of My class.

Comment: Might be clearer with an example.

Comment: However, note that in practice, no dereference would actually be required.

Comment: Oh I think I understand, for example if the memory had been assigned to another object also containing the "DoSomething" function then that function would be called instead? Or if it was just some other data it would simply crash because there is no "DoSomething" function available where the pointer is pointing?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Can you explain why no dereference would be required?

Comment: @mclaassen: Because all the generated code needs to do is call a known function, passing `myclass` as an argument.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah yes of course just the pointer itself gets passed to the function

Comment: @mclaassen I don't entirely understand the execution on the machine level but I would imagine wether or not it runs is based on memory profile rather than name and whatnot? So for example instead of a vtable the object itself holds the function pointer, if there is also a function pointer in the same location as in the original object the second function will be called?
Full disclosure this is an extra credit assignment for my C++ class, understanding security vulnerabilities. I'm relatively new here (long time lurker) so unsure if yall are ok with answering homework related questions :P

Comment: @BrianBTB It's actually different for virtual and non virtual calls. For the non virtual call the compiler already knows the location of the function (it doesn't need an instance of the object to know) and calls it passing the instance in so the method can access members of the instance. For virtual calls then I believe the vtable is stored with the actual instance.

Comment: @mclaassen ah I see Yakk's explaination... OK that makes sense. Then it would crash if any instance members it is looking for aren't available in wherever the pointer is now pointing. Fascinating. I should probably fork the last question this raises for me, essentially how then are members treated (in memory) for example if DoSomething sets the value of MyClass.Counter where Counter is an integer, but DoSomething's THIS is a pointer to a different object how could you predict what would happen? I imagine it wouldn't be based on naming but on memory layout within the class?

Comment: @BrianBTB It would just be undefined behavior. The CPU would likely raise an interrupt because an attempt was made to modify an invalid memory location (like 0). It's possible though that if t that pointer was set to point at some other non MyClass type object that it would corrupt some random member of that instance.

Comment: @mclaassen Excellent! A bit of further reading and I answered my own last question, it would entirely depend on the objects and functions involved, compiler, archtecture, ect. This is such a fascinating subject... I understand it is protocol now for me to mark a correct answer... What is proceedure when answers contain different halfs of the whole answer?

Comment: @BrianBTB Just pick whichever one you think answered the question better.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is undefined behaviour.

The long answer is based off a typical C++ implementation.

For a non-`virtual` method, the method is basically a function with an extra parameter that is automatically passed called `this`: often an atypical calling convention is also used, but that does not matter much.

So `foo->method()` becomes `Foo::method(foo)` in effect, and passing a bad (freed) `foo` is just like passing any other bad/freed parameter.

Relying on this is a bad idea, as the compiler is free to mess with you if you use an invalid `this` to invoke a non-`virtual` method.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make a different interpretation of the OP's question.

If DoSomething is a virtual function, then

```
   myclass->DoSomething () ; // Should be my object
```

requires the compiler to generate code that examines the object reference by my class and determine what DoSomething to call at run time. If myclass has been deleted

```
  delete myclass ;
```

then the behavior during this lookup is undefined and the translation process itself provides a point of failure.

If DoSomething is a non virtual function then, this does not require the compiler to implement a procedure to determine which DoSomething to call at run time. The compile might use the exact same process is uses with a virtual function but this would not strictly be necessary. Assuming that the compiler does not generate code for a run time lookup, doing something like

```
 CALL MyClass_DoSomething
```

then this would not provide a point of failure for an undefined object referenced by myclass. However, the method needs to know which object called it. The compiler is likely to do this as an argument, doing something like for your code:

```
 MOV  EAX, myclass
 CALL MyClass_DoSomething
```

or

```
 PUSH myclass     
 CALL MyClass_DoSomething
```

This reference to the object has undefined, indeterminate behavior.